# Cocoa Binding for bit mask property uses check boxes

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

What is the best way to use Cocoa bindings with checkbox `NSButton`'s and an integer property used as a bit mask?

I have defined this `enum` for the days of the week:

```
typedef enum {
    DayOfWeekSun = 1 << 0,
    DayOfWeekMon = 1 << 1,
    DayOfWeekTue = 1 << 2,
    DayOfWeekWed = 1 << 3,
    DayOfWeekThu = 1 << 4,
    DayOfWeekFri = 1 << 5,
    DayOfWeekSat = 1 << 6
} DaysOfWeek;
```

And I have a property defined on my model (in Core Data, but it doesn't matter):

```
@property NSInteger days;
```

So, for example this property might be set to Sunday and Wednesday as follows:

```
model.days = DayOfWeekSun | DayOfWeekWed;
```

In my NIB I have created checkboxes for Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, etc. and I want to use Cocoa binding to bind these checkboxes to the `days` property.

This is my first try, experimenting a bit. It almost works, but altering the value in the check boxes isn't reflected in the model.

```
@interface WYBDaysOfWeekBitMask : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger daysOfWeek;
@property BOOL monday;
@property BOOL tuesday;
@property BOOL wednesday;
@property BOOL thursday;
@property BOOL friday;
@property BOOL saturday;
@property BOOL sunday;

@end

@implementation DaysOfWeekBitMask

- (void)setDaysOfWeek:(NSInteger)daysOfWeek
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"daysOfWeek"];
    _daysOfWeek = daysOfWeek;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"daysOfWeek"];
}

- (BOOL)sunday
{
    return _daysOfWeek & DayOfWeekSun;
}

- (void)setSunday:(BOOL)sunday
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"sunday"];
    [self setDayOfWeek:sunday dayBitMask:DayOfWeekSun];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"sunday"];
}

[... and so on for the other days ...]

- (void)setDayOfWeek:(BOOL)selected dayBitMask:(DaysOfWeek)mask
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"daysOfWeek"];
    _daysOfWeek = _daysOfWeek & ~mask;
    if (selected) {
        _daysOfWeek = _daysOfWeek | mask;
    }
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"daysOfWeek"];
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSSet *set = nil;

    if ([key isEqualToString:@"daysOfWeek"]) {
        set = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"sunday", @"monday", @"tuesday", @"wednesday", @"thursday", @"friday", @"saturday", nil];
    }
    else if ([key isEqualToString:@"sunday"] ||
             [key isEqualToString:@"monday"] ||
             [key isEqualToString:@"tuesday"] ||
             [key isEqualToString:@"wedneday"] ||
             [key isEqualToString:@"thursday"] ||
             [key isEqualToString:@"friday"] ||
             [key isEqualToString:@"saturday"]) {
        set = [NSSet setWithObject:@"daysOfWeek"];
    }

    return set;
}

@end
```

And this is set as follows in my NIB controller:

```
-(void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    // Manual Bindings
    self.daysOfWeek = [WYBDaysOfWeekBitMask new];
    [self.daysOfWeek bind:@"daysOfWeek" toObject:self.timesArrayController withKeyPath:@"selection.days" options:nil];
}
```

I have a feeling I am going about this the wrong way. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are binding each checkbox in the nib? How?  And what's the purpose of the programmatic binding in your last line of code? You have created something that's exposed a "daysOfWeek" binding?  `bind:toObject:withKeyPath` is generally called on the classes in [the Cocoa Bindings Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/CocoaBindingsRef.html).  And it's not clear that WYBDaysOfWeekBitMask is a subclass of one of those controls.

Comment: Thanks @stevesliva. I'm binding the checkboxes to the `sunday`, `monday`, etc. properties on my `DaysOfWeekBitMask` helper object, just to convert between the integer `days` property (which is bound to the model object) and booleans for each day of the week. It does feel very clunky to me. I am sure there must be a better way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's times like these when KVO seems really powerful. Here's an example of a way you can use KVO to add makeshift properties to your object.

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

// use NS_OPTIONS instead of a typedef enum for bit masks
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, DayOptions) {
    DaySunday = 1 << 0,
    DayMonday = 1 << 1,
    DayTuesday = 1 << 2,
    DayWednesday = 1 << 3,
    DayThursday = 1 << 4,
    DayFriday = 1 << 5,
    DaySaturday = 1 << 6,
};

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSOutlineViewDataSource, NSOutlineViewDelegate>
@property (assign) DayOptions days;
@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

DayOptions optionsForString(NSString *dayString) {
    NSString *day = dayString.lowercaseString;

    if ([day isEqualToString:@"sunday"]) return DaySunday;
    else if ([day isEqualToString:@"monday"]) return DayMonday;
    else if ([day isEqualToString:@"tuesday"]) return DayTuesday;
    else if ([day isEqualToString:@"wednesday"]) return DayWednesday;
    else if ([day isEqualToString:@"thursday"]) return DayThursday;
    else if ([day isEqualToString:@"friday"]) return DayFriday;
    else if ([day isEqualToString:@"saturday"]) return DaySaturday;
    return 0;
}

@implementation AppDelegate

// return an NSNumber representing the presence of a bit mask
- (id)valueForUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key {
    DayOptions options = optionsForString(key);
    if (options != 0) {
        return @((BOOL)(self.days & options));
    }
    return [super valueForKey:key];
}

// a NO value will remove the mask from -days and a YES value will add it
- (void)setValue:(id)value forUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key {
    DayOptions options = optionsForString(key);
    if (options != 0 && [value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        BOOL flag = [value boolValue];
        if (flag)
            self.days |= options;
        else
            self.days &= ~options;
    } else {
        [super setValue:value forUndefinedKey:key];
    }
}
// send KVO notifications whenever -days gets changed
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:(NSString *)key {
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"sunday"] ||
        [key isEqualToString:@"monday"] ||
        [key isEqualToString:@"tuesday"] ||
        [key isEqualToString:@"wednesday"] ||
        [key isEqualToString:@"thursday"] ||
        [key isEqualToString:@"friday"] ||
        [key isEqualToString:@"saturday"]) {
        return [NSSet setWithObject:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(days))];
    }
    return [super keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:key];
}

@end
```

**This code is untested but should compile and I think it'd work well**

So you would add a `Days` property (I renamed your DaysOfWeek to Days) to whatever class is in charge of your nib, and bind each checkbox to sunday, monday, etc. properties on that. The class uses KVO methods to return real values for unknown key paths and will also send KVO notifications when `-days` gets changed.

So there is no need to create an extra class to wrap around your enum.

Comment: That is brilliant @AlexZielenski. Thank you so much for providing such a full and helpful answer. And for teaching me a bit more about KVO in the process.